# Android: Recent apps seem to have Google-provided ads, is there some new API for this?

Tags: android, admob, ads

Several recent applications (e.g. Shazam) have text and image ads which are handled by Google.  I can't find how they did this.  Is there some new API that you can use to display ads given some key, similar to how the maps API works? Or is this something that developers individually negotiate?

Specifically I'm interested in Google's ads.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular API for this comes from AdMob, take a look:
http://www.admob.com/

Comment: I spotted AdMob right away when I was trying to figure out how Shazam go their ads, but I can't find anything about how Shazam actually works with Google.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the SDK to support this, no. However, if you go to [Google's AdSense page](https://www.google.com/adsense/) there's information on Mobile ads.

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently launched AdSense for Mobile and you could apply to be a part of the beta.

http://www.google.com/ads/mobileapps/developerform.html

Note that you need to **apply** and the requirements are an app which will generate at least 100,000 page views per day.

This is the program Shazam is using.